# Some HTML/CSS to get around a drawback in Struts2

Tags: html, css, struts2, html-table

I am trying to get an HTML page like: http://jsbin.com/awoco.

This is a JSP page so it will include scriptlets.  Final HTML output will be kind of like this (tags unclosed to save space):

```
<%
Iterator it = MyList.iterator()
      While (it.hasNext())
      SomeClass all = it.next();
      SomeClass a = it.next();
      SomeClass b = it.next();
%>
      <tr> 
        <td rowspan=3 valign=top>Red<td><%=all.Name()%><td><%=all.price()%><td><%=all.originalPrice()%> 
      </tr> 
      <tr> 
        <td><%=a.Name()%><td><%=a.price()%><td><%=a.originalPrice()%> 
      </tr>  
      <tr >
        <td><%=b.Name()%><td><%=b.price()%><td><%=b.originalPrice()%>
      </tr>
```

As you can see, I have to call `next()` 3 times inside the while loop. This is because the source of the data is a List populated that way, and I have to show the data in the exact same manner as in the link provided above.

Is there a way to change the HTML output somehow so that I don't have to call `next()` more than once, but still get the same table structure?

Comment: I'm afraid that I can't offer useful advice regarding your problem, but would advise that I don't think the question has anything to do with html or css, since the question seems to be about how to efficiently create output from a source, rather than how to present it.

Answer (score 0):

Change your data structures. `MyList` should be list of (something like) AgregateClass which will contain 3 members of type `SomeClass` (all,a,b) and then simply iterate through `MyList`.

Just few tips: 
If you are using Struts2 you can use `<s:iterator>` tag to iterate through collections. [documentation](http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/iterator)

Since JSP 2.0 or so you can write `${b.price}` instead of `<%=b.price()%>`

You should change tags you added to your question as it has nothing to do with html or css.